# Job is not creating pod

Tags: docker, jobs, minikube

I'm using minikube and I'm trying to make a Job, everything seems fine but it's not creating pod. 
Here's my yaml file:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: calculator
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: calculator
        image: mzylowski/life-calculator:0.1
        command: ["universer",  "39934"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

Also when I'm trying to find what's wrong I'm getting this:

[image]

Comment: What it shows when you do `kubectl get job`? What are the events shown in `kubectl describe job calculator`?

Comment: There's job created `COMPLETIONS 0/1`
And this screenshot above is showing what i can see after `kubectl describe job calculator`

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the `Events` in bottom left. I think it'd be better to also open an issue in Minikube GitHub. As it seems to me, your configurations are valid and it must have create a pod for your job. I also tested your yaml in my cluster and it worked.

Comment: Hi, can You share what environment are You running You minikube on? Also the version of Minikube and VM driver You are using.